# Oracle 19 container database with different charactersets

Tags: oracle

Is it possible in Oracle SE2 19.10 (newest patch) to have container database with different database character sets e.g.
First database with character set EE8MSWIN1250
Second database with character set AL32UTF8
Regards,
Groxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *container* databases, or stand-alone database you can create them with whatever character set you want.

For *pluggable* databases within a container, it will depend on what version of Oracle you have. For Oracle 12.2 or later, if the *container* database has a character set of AL32UTF8, then the pluggable databases within that container may have any character set.

That said, there is no way to create a PDB directly with a different character set than the container DB. You would have to create the PDB in a container with the same character set, then migrate it to a container with a different character set.

See here for all the details: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-pdb-character-sets-12cr2

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I meant to have PDB databases, each PDB with different character set. For example, one PDB with EE8MSWIN1250 , other PDB with AL32UTF8. I understand this should be possible to achieve with 19c?

Comment: As described in the link I shared, there is currently no way - even with 19c - to create a PDB directly with a different character set than the container it was created within. In order to have different character sets for PDBs, they must be created in separate containers (each with appropriate character sets) and then migrated/combined in a common container that uses AL32UTF8.